# Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code

Tags: android

i'm using Youtube .jar to show video youtube player and i got render error

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:

- com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView (Open Class, Show 
    Exception, Clear Cache)

    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.
```

My Code XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:background="#fff"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should ignore it , if you are using jar. Basically not always android layout preview renders the custom layout, because it requires few classes to load which fails sometime. So ignore it and view on emulator or actual device, it should work because code is correct,

Comment: ohhh overall is okay ? ok thank you, sir